# Is there a term for words like "said", "asked", or "replied" appearing in a dialogue?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a term for words like "said", "asked", or "replied" appearing in a dialogue?

For example:

> "Where did you go," asked the turtle.
>
> "I went to the mall," replied the rabbit.

Is there a technical term describing those words in the above dialogue?

Comment: These are all in the category called "Speech act verbs", which is much larger than you might suspect. Consider _snap, cackle,_ and _pipe up,_ for instance: _"Get out!", he snapped; "I've got you now", she cackled; "I know where he went!", piped up one child._

Answer (score 1):

It's the **narration** that accompanies the dialogue.

> [**narration**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/narration) - *noun* - "the act or process or an instance of narrating"
>
> [**narrate**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/narrate) - *verb* - to speak in accompaniment of (a film, television programme, etc)